# Is there an easy way to copy the ActiveSheets .PageSetup?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Seems simple and probably a case of "It's monday" but I can't find the answer to this.. without having to record all the pagesetup variables in strings beforehand, is there a way to copy a worksheets .pageSetup property?

in a macro im running, I create a new page, paste some data, change a bunch of pagesetup settings, then print. I was hoping there was a way i could save the page setup before hand, and apply it again afterwards so my users don't have to worry about fixing settings ever.

I tried:

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws = ActiveSheet.pageSetup

'settings change / print

ActiveSheet.pagesetup = ws.pagesetup
```

that doesnt work because ws.pagesetup is now linked to activesheet.pagesetup, so as soon as i change the active sheets settings, ws's settings get changed too.

I also tried `set ws = sheets(1)` because the new page is never the first page, but then with that one `ActiveSheet.pagesetup = ws.pagesetup` doesnt work either, it says `object doesn't support this property or method`

Is there a simple way? must I have 20 different string variables to hold all the current pagesetup variables?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tired just making a copy of the page you want the setup from?

Comment: well the page I want the setup from is the newly created one. so when i go `set ws = sheets.add..` ws is the sheet I want to save the pagesetup from. and I suppose I could do `set ws2 = ws` where ws2 is a worksheet object but then Afterwards again, I want to do something like `ws2.pagesetup = ws.pagesetup`. if i did something like ws = ws2 then i'd lose all the data in ws right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I want to accomplish something like this I'll save all my formatting and pagesetup stuff to a hidden sheet. At the right time I'll have my code copy and paste everything where I need it. In this case it would probably be easiest to start by making a copy of the hidden sheet. Then dump in your data and work from there.

Comment: Ahh, so I could make ws my new sheet, make a hidden sheet using ws, then put my data in ws, then change the settings, then print, then copy and paste data (not settings) from ws to hiddensheet, then do like ws = hidden sheet, which will overwrite the page setup settings on ws with hiddensheet's, but I will have saved the data, not exactly pretty but I think it'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than coping page setting from a master sheet to other sheets:

1. Create the master sheet
2. Establish the page settings for this single sheet
3. Make copies of the master
4. Populate the copies with data, formulas, etc.

In other words, anticipate your needs and setup the sheets in advance.

Comment: there's no real master sheet, theres however many sheets the user is working with, and they do things like print and change etc... and they may run the macro at any time.. and when they run the macro, certain print settings are required, but I dont want them to have to change their print settings back to they way they had previously to the macro.